# Create separate objects in an array dynamically

Tags: javascript

Here is the piece of code I'm confused with:

```
    let includes = []; // the array that I'm trying to fill with objects
    let obj = {};

    for (let a = 0; a < linked.related.length; a++) {
         for (let b = 1; b < linked.related[a].length; b++) {

             if(structures.includes(linked.related[a][b])){                                                                        
                        includes.push(obj[linked.related[a][b]] = a); // HERE IS THE PROBLEM!                                              
              }
          }
     }
```

I just want to create objects with  `linked.related[a][b]` as their property and `a` from first for loop as their values. The problem is I can't figure out a working way.

I've tried this with no success:

```
includes.push(obj[linked.related[a][b]] = a);
```

The desired result should be like:

```
[ {linked.related[a¹][b] : a¹}, {linked.related[a²][b] : a²}, ...]
```

Here is a working example code:

```js
let structures = ["to protect you", 'to find you' , "gtg", 'I was sent',"to moon"];
let linked = {
    construct: [  

    [ 'I send', 'I sent', 'I was sent', 'I have been sent'],
    [],
    ["to moon", "to earth", "to Mars"],
    []

    ],

    related:   [  

    ['I was sent', 'I was forced'], 
    ['to protect you', 'to protect us', 'to protect me'], 
    [ "gtg"],
    ['to find you', 'to judge you', 'to protect you', "to peneterate you"],
    ['to protect you','to find you', 'to love you'] 

    ]
}

add_zeros();
function add_zeros(){
 
 for (let i = 0; i < linked.related.length; i++) {
  linked.related[i].unshift(0)
 }
}


// And Here Is Where The Problem Exist
 let includes = [];
  var obj = {};
     for (let a = 0; a < linked.related.length; a++) {
           for (let b = 1; b < linked.related[a].length; b++) {

               if(structures.includes(linked.related[a][b])){                                                       
                includes.push(obj[linked.related[a][b]] = a);                                                    }
             }
      }
console.log(includes)
```

Comment: There's only one object in your script: `let obj = {}`. Your script only changes the content of this one object. Just move the `let obj = ...` into the `if` or just use a object literal without storing it in a variable.

Comment: That didn't work...

Comment: `includes.push(obj[linked.related[a][b]] = a)` evaluates the expression and pushes `a` to the array. So you end up with an array of numbers

Comment: I have problem with this : `includes.push(obj[linked.related[a][b]] = a);`

Comment: @adiga  I know... how to fix that?

Comment: Please post a valid expected output in JSON format. It's unclear as of now. What is `a²`?

Comment: `linked.related[a²][b]` is an string ...

Comment: I'll try to update the question ...

Comment: The question is updated...

Comment: Close voter, please provide your reason

Answer (score -1):

I dont know how to construct a¹, ... in javascript string. But seems you need:

```js
let structures = ["to protect you", 'to find you' , "gtg", 'I was sent',"to moon"];
let linked = {
    construct: [  

    [ 'I send', 'I sent', 'I was sent', 'I have been sent'],
    [],
    ["to moon", "to earth", "to Mars"],
    []

    ],

    related:   [  

    ['I was sent', 'I was forced'], 
    ['to protect you', 'to protect us', 'to protect me'], 
    [ "gtg"],
    ['to find you', 'to judge you', 'to protect you', "to peneterate you"],
    ['to protect you','to find you', 'to love you'] 

    ]
}

add_zeros();
function add_zeros(){
 
 for (let i = 0; i < linked.related.length; i++) {
  linked.related[i].unshift(0)
 }
}


// And Here Is Where The Problem Exist
 let includes = [];
 var obj;
 for (let a = 0; a < linked.related.length; a++) {
           for (let b = 1; b < linked.related[a].length; b++) {

               if (structures.includes(linked.related[a][b])){                   
                obj = {};
                obj[`linked.related[a^${a+1}][b]`] = `a^${a+1}`;
                includes.push(obj);                                                    }
             }
      }
console.log(includes)
```

Comment: Dear downvoter, I know you didnt get the question. The only issue is superscripting value in a js variable which seems not possible. I would like OP's comment to verify the need,